# Identifying grid system in Canada

Tags: coordinate-system, grids-graticules, canada

I'm trying to identify this grid system that consists of two letter followed by two numbers.

[image]

If it helps I know GU37 is defined by the following vertices:

```
  Lat (North)   Lng (West)
1 48° 30' 00"   64° 00' 00"
2 48° 40' 00"   64° 00' 00"
3 48° 40' 00"   63° 50' 00"
4 48° 30' 00"   63° 50' 00"
5 48° 30' 00"   64° 00' 00"
```

Point references are based on the geodesic system North American Datum 1983 (NAD83)

My ultimate goal is to be able to convert a point using PostGIS to a grid name.

Given that I know an origin - GU37 - and I know this is a 10 minute grid (I think) - is this something I could generate?

Comment: Perhaps best asking Fisheries and Oceans Canada

Comment: @nmtoken - I'm trying that simultaneously. Like I said, new to GIS and I wasn't sure if this was something somebody on here might recognize quickly. Getting answers from government agencies is mind-numbingly slow and complicated.

Comment: Can you share the url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was later able to find a doc that contained the grid specifications. It is indeed a 10 minute grid that starts at (FX1) at 52°30'00"N 70°00'00"W.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XINqo.jpg

EDIT: My finished grid in QGIS after I added in the lobster fishing areas (LFAs) in the Gulf/Scotia-Fundy region, everything of which has been overlaid on top of the NAFO zones:

[image]

What a nightmare it is asking DFO for geospatial data, or even DMS coordinates. This exercise was WAY harder than it needed to be.

Comment: How does the lettering work?

Comment: This must be the best kept Canadian secret. Where did you manage to find the grid specifications?

Comment: @TomazicM - I didn't "find" the grid specifications, per se, I interpreted them from the image in my post. DFO publishes all kinds of (electronic) hard-copy maps in PDF format, but ask them for the coordinates and you'll get stuck in a bureaucracy nightmare (not sure why - it's the public's data, isn't it?). Stumbling through a few places I saw a mention of a "10 minute grid" and then I saw that's what this is. Then I just picked a grid name and wrote a script to generate the grid. I didn't extrapolate so I don't know the latitude for "A1", but it should be easy enough to determine.

Comment: @nmtoken - I didn't extrapolate to "A1" so I don't know where it starts. But it just increments - "AB, AC, ...AZ, BA, BB, ... FHZ, FGA, ...etc" north to south

Comment: But you did find file `Carte1_Quadrilateres-Map1_Grids.pdf ` somewhere.

Comment: @TomazicM I work for a startup that has had numerous communications with DFO over the last couple of years. It happened to be one of the many pieces of correspondence when I was sifting through it all - it came from DFO, just unclear from whom. When I compared it with [this map](https://www.dfo-mpo.gc.ca/fisheries-peches/commercial-commerciale/atl-arc/narw-bnan/2020/right-whale-baleine-noires-0715-eng.html) it appears to be roughly correct. So I can only assume this PDF I stumbled across is still correct.

Comment: It's always okay to accept your own answer; it tells future readers that an answer has been accepted and (ever so slightly) improves the sites statistics, and doesn't generate any direct reputation increase for you, so no reason not to I think, as long as the answer "solved your problem".